# Blender does not display objects's shape

Tags: rendering

I'm new to Blender, I just started learning a couple days ago.

I have one question about the preview. My Blender seems to not displaying anything in Material Preview mode, even though I edited the objects' material. As you can see in the second picture, the first picture you can clearly see the objects in Solid mode.

Is it that something is wrong with Blender or did I edit something I'm not supposed to ? I'm using Blender 2.83 as well as 2.91

Sorry for my bad English :).
[image: Solid Mode]

[image: Meterial Preview]

Comment: there's a problem with the latest AMD driver, maybe it's the problem here?

Comment: No doubt - AMD Drivers - Roll back to earlier version to fix.

Comment: Correct! It was the AMD driver. I fixed it!! Thanks a lot guys. :)